# trying to find number of directories in a path using a regexp

Tags: regex, bash

I need to find how many directories are in a given path. 
For example `testdir1/testdir2/testdir3/` should return three directories accounting for the last `/` that has no text after it. 
This is all in a bash environment.

This is what I tried and came up with, and somewhat works, but I get four directories instead of three:

`tr '/.' '\n' <<< testdir1/testdir2/testdir3/ | wc -l`

How would I write the task *find all /'s except for the one at the end without any text after it*?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not introduce links in your question without explaining the readers what they point to. Happy scripting!

Comment: What is wrong with subtracting 1 from the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `herestring` `<<<` with ProcessSubstituion `<( )`, because the herestring adds an additional newline

```
tr '/' '\n' < <(printf '%s' testdir1/testdir2/testdir3/) | wc -l
```

Output

```
3
```

Or just remove the trailing slash `/`

```
tr '/' '\n' <<< testdir1/testdir2/testdir3 | wc -l
```

Output

```
3
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked!. Didn't know that. I can't remove the / as I'm using it in a script which has to be prepared for that use case. I was also able to find another solution ` tr '/.' '\n' <<< testdir1/testdir2/testdir3/ | grep -v "^$" | wc -l `

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK

```
:=>echo "testdir1/testdir2/testdir3/"  | awk -F'/' '{ if ($NF =="") print NF-1; else NF }' 
3
:=>
```

Explanation:

```
awk -F'/'  -- Set field seprator as / 

{ if ($NF =="") -- NF is number of field in current record. $NF -- value is last field 
print NF-1; --  IF last field is empty print NF-1 else all fields
```

Edit:  Using grep

```
:=>echo "testdir1/testdir2/testdir3/"  | grep -o '/' |  wc -l 
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
tr -cd "/" <<< "testdir1/testdir2/testdir3/" | wc -c
```

`tr -cd "/"` removes all characters of the input other than "/" and the output will be `///`. Then `wc -c` counts the number of bytes.